# Ldap and attributes(LDAP)

Tags: java, ldap

Hi I am a developer but new to ldap programming. I was able to our Ldap server by providing the DN=ou=app1,ou=development,ou=Group and set my search level to  subtree_scope and was able to get to on level down which put me at `DN=cn=admin,DN=ou=app1,ou=development,ou=Group`. By expanding this DN i see `Member(4)`,`OU(1)`, `cn(1)`,and Objectclasses: `top` and `groupOfNames`. I am trying to access the 4 users with `uid=user` entries. I got the below message when i tried to access `uid`:

UID...  class javax.naming.directory.SearchResult

null
Found cn=Admin:

### Attributes are..    No attributes

The following is the snippet of my code. I can provide more if needed

```
    controls.setReturningAttributes("uid");
    String filter="(objectClass=groupOfNames)"; 

        NamingEnumeration objs = ctx.search("",filter, controls); 


        while (objs.hasMoreElements())
                {

                SearchResult match = (SearchResult)objs.nextElement();

               System.out.println(" UID...\t"+ match.getClass());
               System.out.println(match.getClassName());
               System.out.println("Found "+match.getName()+":");
               System.out.println("Attributes are..\t"+match.getAttributes());


                Attributes attrs = match.getAttributes();
                NamingEnumeration e = attrs.getAll();


                while (e.hasMoreElements())
                {

                    Attribute attr = (Attribute) e.nextElement();
                   System.out.println("Attribute and its class..\t"+attr.getClass());


                }
                System.out.println("---------------------------------------");
            }
                }
```

Comment: I don't understand the error. Please provide the full stack trace.

Comment: @EJP I asked OP to provide more code.

Comment: attributesToReturn = null; // return all

Comment: @Prince No you didn't. You asked him to provide a non-existent stack trace. It's up there in black and white. And if he had specified attributesToReturn as null it would work. Ergo he hasn't.

Answer (score -1):

The SearchControls define the attributes to be returned by the search. You must have set its 'returningAttributes' property to 'new String[0]'. Leave it at null to get all attributes, or specify the ones you want.

Comment: just a fyi: he set the `returningAttributes` property not to `new String[0]` but to `uid` (in his code)

Comment: @ljgw Impossible. The method takes an array, not a String. He can't be running that code.

Comment: curious... I guess I must read the code I see in the post perhaps as   `String[] attrs = new String[1];` `attrs[0] = "uid";`
  `controls.setReturningAttributes(attrs);`

Comment: @ljgw Of course, but that's not what he posted. If that was the case it would work. Ergo that isn't the case.

Comment: groupOfNames does not permit 'uid'. Out of curiosity, is there an aux class in the questioners entry that permits 'uid' ... Otherwise, why request that attribute?